# grpc architecture : where should be caching layer be?

Tags: c#, caching, microservices, grpc

We have a monolithic system that we are currently breaking into microservices using gRPC. Currently, we are using enyim caching in C# client in our monolithic code.

While creating our first gRPC service, we are confused that where should caching layer be:

1. Should it be moved to gRPC service code for this service? This way each service will have its caching code. This would lead to lots of duplicate caching code.
2. Should we create dll for caching related code and use it in new gRPC microservice? We would still need to place duplcate configurations across each gRPC service.
3. Handle caching from monolithic code only and call gRPC service only in case for cache miss?

Suggestions?

Comment: this is very interesting question, but my thinking is grpc is just about transport layer, anything in application layer like authn/r, caching, should be handled in a gateway-like thing.

Comment: yeah @chenrui, looks better to put it in API Gateway. So, services should only extract out data, correct? Do you have any good links that suggest not using cache at service level and to put it at the gateway?

Comment: To be honest, all approaches you mentioned can be appropriate depending on the situation and without knowing more details about your system, it is impossible to decide which approach is the "best". Others are correct in saying that something you should also investigate is adding caching in an intermediate layer (like gateway) - but ability to use this kind of caching depends on the nature of your requests (they need to be idempotent).

Answer (score 0):

I was just browsing through when I checked this:

[image: API Gateway Responsibilities]

Caching at API Gateway makes lot of sense as it would save call to a service and caching code would not be duplicated at each service but would remain centralized with API Gateway itself.